# Unable to modify permissions of folders on Mac (Mojave)

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod, macos-mojave

I am new to Macs and I am trying to run some interesting stats on my iMessages using the code runner extension on VSCode. I've been following this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-you-can-access-your-entire-imessage-history-on-your-mac-f8878276c6e9

However, when I run the line `conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/<username>/Library/Messages/chat.db')`
I get the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

Based off what I can tell my issue is that VScode doesn't have the right permissions to access the ~/Library/Messages folder and possibly the chat.db as well. First, I ran `ls -l` on Library and the result is `drwx---rwx` for Messages. So I tried to use both `chmod a+rwx Messages` and `sudo chmod a+rwx Messages` to open permissions to everything but got the error `chmod: Unable to change file mode on Messages: Operation not permitted` both times. 
Am I doing something wrong and/or is there a better way to do this? Or is it just not possible to change the permissions of this folder?

Comment: My exact problem, solution fixes.

Answer (score 5):

After some more creative searching I discovered that it was an Issue with Mojave's System Integrity Protection (SIP) and can be solved by giving the desired apps full disk access in Settings>Security&Privacy>Privacy>FullDiskAccess.

[Solution found here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/ls-operation-not-permitted-mojave-security)